# What information does the Intro to Adventurers League D&D Celebration 2021 day one segment cover?

Tags: dnd-adventurers-league, convention

What information does the Intro to Adventurers League [D&D Celebration](https://dndcelebration.com/) 2021 day one segment cover?

I'm looking for a concise summary of the information contained in the convention segment.

Comment: You're talking about the segment with Bee, Ma'at, and Amy that will start in around 1.5 hours, right?

Comment: @RedOrca yup that one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Largely basic information, with a few small reveals

*The full [D&D Celebration Day 1 VOD](https://youtu.be/nUv6DEL6bYA?t=8880) is available on YouTube. The AL segment begins at 2:28:00.*

Bee, Ma'at, and Amy explained the basics of Adventurers League, such as:

- Everyone uses the same set of rules, in order to keep everyone on the same playing field.
- Portability continues to be a major pillar of AL, allowing you to play the same character at game stores, conventions, online, and at home.
- AL campaigns, including Forgotten Realms and Ravenloft: Mist Hunters. (They didn't mention the Eberron campaign - Oracle of War - as Mist Hunters lead into a discussion about content warnings.)
- The official [D&D Discord server](https://discord.gg/dnd), with channels for AL and non-AL content for both players and DMs.

They also revealed that a few items can be found on the [D&D Celebration 2021 map](https://dndcelebration.com/map) (without telling us specifically how to find them). **The map includes the following previews for upcoming content:**

> The upcoming Drakewarden ranger and updates to dragonborn.

They also discussed content warnings and safety tools:

- TTRPG Safety Toolkit (discussed in greater detail in the [Mist Hunters Safety Kit](https://yawningportal.dnd.wizards.com/blog/mist-hunters-safety-kit/) blog post)
- [X-Card](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/150350/47185)
- [Lines and Veils](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/30913/47185)

Lastly, they responded to a few questions from chat:

- They gave several suggestions for accommodations for players with disabilities.
- They clarified that rewards discovered in the D&D Celebration 2021 map count as **event awards**<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> Event awards have special rules in the newly-released Forgotten Realms PG. You may only have one event award active on your character when you sit down at a given table.

Comment: I will accept this right away; it seems appropriate in the context :) Thank you.